# Why does python think there are 6 positional arguments when I only have 5?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to use that Domino's pizza api with this program I'm making but I want to use user inputs instead of coded-in customer data. To do so, I coded this:

```py
from pizzapi import Customer
address = input("Street Address: ") + ', ' + input('City: ') + ', ' + input('State Abbreviation: ') + ', ' + input('5-Digit Zip Code: ')
customer = Customer(input('First Name: '), input('Last Name: '), input('Email: '), input('Phone Number: '), str(address))
print(customer)
```

but when I try to run it, I get this error:

```py
customer = Customer(input('First Name: '), input('Last Name: '), input('Email: '), input('Phone Number: '), str(address))
TypeError: Customer.__init__() takes from 1 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

How do I get rid of this error? I'm only inputting 5 parameters?

edit: the customer module looks like this:

```py
class Customer:
    """The Customer who orders a pizza."""

    def __init__(self, fname='', lname='', email='', phone='', address=None):
        self.first_name = fname.strip()
        self.last_name = lname.strip()
        self.email = email.strip()
        self.phone = str(phone).strip()
        self.str_address = address
        self.address = Address(*address.split(','))

    def save(self, filename="customers/customer1.json"):
        """
        saves the current customer to a .json file for loading later
        """
        if not filename.startswith("customers"):
            filename = "customers/" + filename
        json_dict = {"first_name": self.first_name,
             "last_name": self.last_name,
             "email": self.email,
             "phone": self.phone,
             "address": self.str_address}

        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            json.dump(json_dict, f)

    @staticmethod
    def load(filename):
        """
        load and return a new customer object from a json file
        """
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)

            customer = Customer(data["first_name"], 
                                data["last_name"],
                                data["email"],
                                data["phone"],
                                data["address"])
        return customer

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Name: {} {}\nEmail: {}\nPhone: {}\nAddress: {}".format(
            self.first_name,
            self.last_name,
            self.email,
            self.phone,
            self.address,
        )
```

Comment: Post the signature of Customer constructor

Comment: In absence of actual details: because you forgot that `__init__` starts as `def __init__(self, ..... )` and you gave it more arguments than it actually allows. So: show the actual code for the Customer class's `__init__` function?

Comment: The Customer class has a method __init__(). This method takes as their first parameter the class itself. While this is implicit when initializing the class, it is explicitly declared in the class method signature as the parameter 'self', the first parameter in any class method. When python raises the error it counts self as one of the parameters eve though you do not need to include it in the init call

Comment: The error doesn't match the code you showed. Did you save the customer file and re-run the script? The class code you show has 1-6 positional arguments, not 5. Proof: ```class Customer:
    def __init__(self, a='', b='', c='', d='', e=None):pass
; Customer(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7)``` which gives the error `TypeError: Customer.__init__() takes from 1 to 6 positional arguments but 7 were given` (`self` counts as a positional arg)

Comment: The class definition you posted looks like it should *not* give that error - are you sure you're running the latest definition of the class? (Note that `import` will *not* reload the module definition - you need to `from importlib import reload` and then `reload(pizzapi)`.

Comment: How are you running this code? The command line? In an IDE?

Comment: I have to disagree that this is a duplicate of the listed question.  The error message may be the same, but the cause is clearly not.

Comment: Since its not clear how this could happen, you could add `print(__file__)` to the .py file that has the Customer class in it. Outside of your IDE, go to that file and see if it has the right code.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to force Python to load the latest definition of the module the class is in.

To be clear, Python says there are six arguments because it is counting the implicit `self` argument.

But the real strange thing is why it's saying it expects 1-5 arguments instead of 1-6. The `Customer` definition you posted has the right number of parameters in the `__init__` method that the error you're reporting wouldn't happen.

This suggests that your Python process is using a different definition of `Customer`. I can think of a few possibilities:

0. Make sure you save your changes to the `pizzapi` module file where you define `Customer` before running the code. (This might not be obvious if you are used to setups where you don't have to save code to try running it, but most IDEs for Python, and the raw `python` command itself, run the code you have saved, not the code as it is in your editor.)
1. There is a module with the same name in a different location which is being loaded first. (Perhaps an older copy of `pizzapi` that you saved by making a copy?)
2. There is another import running later in your code which gets another `Customer` definition from a different module (a `from example import *` could do it, if the `example` module has a `Customer` defined).
3. An older definition of the same module was already cached in the running Python process (such as when you use Jupyter/iPython, run `python` in a terminal to get a REPL, or have a little live Python panel in your IDE).

You can easily check the first problem: do `import pizzapi` and then `print(pizzapi.__file__)`. That will tell you what exact file path the `pizzapi` module is being loaded from. Check carefully if that's exactly the file that has your latest `Customer` definition.

The second is similarly easy to check: just run `print(Customer.__module__)` *right before* the `customer = Customer(...)` line. This will show you where the `Customer` being used in that line is coming from.

Once the first and second are ruled out or fixed, we get to the third one:

When a Python process runs `import pizzapi` or `from pizzapi import Customer`, it caches the definition of `pizzapi`. After that, even if you change the definition of `Customer`, a second `import pizzapi` or `from pizzapi import Customer` will *not* pick up the changes.

One way to do this is to just quit the Python process and start over.

Another way is to use [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload):

1. First make sure to run `import pizzapi` before the `reload(pizzapi)` if you haven't already.
2. Then do `from importlib import reload` and `reload(pizzapi)`.
3. Finally, you'll need to re-run imports of specific things from the module  such as `from pizzapi import Customer`.

Comment: To be clear, this is only the case if you are running in some sort of a shell like maybe jupyter. If you re-run on the command line or select "run" in an IDE, everything starts from scratch and you don't need to do the reload thing - do you have to save any changes to the .py file of course.

Comment: yeah I'm just using standard Visual Studio Code. I'm still new to this whole programming thing so I'm not really sure how to fix this.

Comment: @tdelaney Crucial ambiguity: "if you re-run on the command line" - if you rerun a Python script from a shell (such as `bash`, PowerShell, and so on) you don't need reload - but if you are in the middle of a `python` REPL (which could be reasonably called a "command line" or "shell") and re-run Python statements in it, you do need reload.

Comment: @VulnerabilityVigilante - If you are in the "run" menu and select "Start Debugging" or "Run without debugging", then this answer isn't for you.

Comment: Um, by "re-run on the command line" I meant "re-run on the command line". I think you are stretching to find some sort of ambiguity. Trying to define command line as REPL just seems to confuse the issue to me.

Comment: @tdelaney with people new to programming the odds are very high that they look at the interactive `python` REPL and think "that sure looks like a command line to me". Especially because it is literally a line-oriented interface into which you type commands.